# Allow anonymous user to start workflow in MOSS 2007

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I need to send email using workflow in 2007 MOSS when an anonymous user adds an item in the list.

With logged in users, workflow gets completed successfully, but with anonymous user, the list item gets added but workflow does not start.

What configurations are needed to allow anonymous users to start a workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the actions inside the workflow, you need to add an impersonation step to run as the author of the workflow. Edit the workflow in SharePoint Designer, and wrap the actions in an impersonation step.

For SP2007: You need to design your workflow in Visual Studios using the `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges`:

Comment: Hi Mike, I need to do it in sharepoint 2007. I think impersonation step does not work in 2007.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: So is it not possible to allow anonymous users to access workflow just by configuration? I need to write code for that,is it so?

Comment: Yes. here is an article on how more to do this in SharePoint 2007: http://cticoder.wordpress.com/2008/12/24/anonymous-workflow-execution-in-sharepoint-2007/